# Labeling contours in open layers 3.17.1

Tags: openlayers, kml, openlayers-3

I am plotting some contours from KML that is provided server side.  What I'd like to do is add a label for each contour near the edge of the viewport, as per the view below:

[image]

My current approach is to walk around each edge of the map and use forEachFeatureAtPixel to determine if a contour/feature is found at [x, y].  If a contour is found, the label is added relative to the current pixel, and a "hasLabel" property for the feature is added (and set to true), so that only one label gets added per contour/feature.

If the user changes the viewport (via zoom or translation), the labels are removed and the same process is rerun to add the labels in the correct position.

Some customers have complained that there is a significant delay (~10s) between the contours being drawn and the labels added - I don't observe this on my dev machine but it is rather high spec.

My question is, is there a faster way to calculate the positions of the labels?  (Some built-in OpenLayers function that lists all features extending beyond the current view perhaps?)

Addition:

I've made the KML source for the two sets of contours available at:

https://lqsts.blob.core.windows.net/temp/DayContours.kml
https://lqsts.blob.core.windows.net/temp/MinuteContours.kml

Comment: You can do this using `jsts` lib. Run an intersection of your current mbr with your contours and place a label at the intersection points. Of course that means that you have to include jsts library. If you provide your code to generate contour I will make a fiddle to demostrate.

Comment: Many thanks indeed for the offer!  I have added links to the KML sources files for the two sets of contours (green and blue).  A fiddle for either set using JSTS would be very helpful indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `jsts` library for the solution I provide. 
To do so just include the [jsts.js](http://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/1.2.0/jsts.min.js) file. This is the latest version and to be honest is the first time I have test it and seems to behave great.

Here is your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/3j4dw90q/) 
Its not final but most of the job is done, so you can test if it is faster than the solution you allready have.

Comment: This EXACTLY what I needed.  I've just finished implementing it into my solution and it definitely works faster than my approach.  Many thanks indeed!